# What exactly is a cache and how can i create one?

Tags: caching

I've seen the word "cache" everywhere, from my phone (there's an option to remove the cache) to my 2DS (the photo cache [phtcache.bin]) and i just don't know what it is.

I tried searching on the internet but i didn't find anything that explained what it was or how to create one.